# Kotlin Android tengo problemas con el FileReader(filePath) abriendo archivos CSV desde la memoria externa

Tags: android, csv, kotlin, filereader

El fileReader no lee el archivo, intente resolverlo por mi cuenta pero no encuentro nada que me ayude... ademas soy muy novato y no entiendo para nada la documentación de android

-ya implemente los permisos para leer y escribir la memoria externa

-Estoy llamando al explorador desde algun boton de un menu

```
        R.id.updateClients -> {

            val fileintent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            fileintent.type = "text/csv"
            try {
                startActivityForResult(fileintent, 1)
            } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                m.mensaje("No tienes explorador de archivos, instala uno")
            }

            true
        }
```

-Luego en base al resultado de la actividad, tras seleccionar el archivo csv, envio un ¿Path? que contiene /external_files/documents/clientes.csv al dataBaseHandler

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    val filepath = data?.data!!.path
    if (filepath!!.contains("/root_path")) filepath =
        filepath.replace("/root_path", "")
    //el path resultante es /external_files/documents/clientes.csv
    val dbc = DbClientsHandler(this)
    dbc.deleteClient()
    dbc.insertData(filepath)

}
```

-El cual hace esto con el filePath:

fun insertData(filepath: String?) {

```
    val code = 0
    val name = 1
    val company = 2
    val direction = 3
    val neigh = 4
    val phone = 5
    val db = this.writableDatabase

    try {
        val file = FileReader(filepath)
        //Leer el encabezado del archivo CSV
        val fileReader = BufferedReader(file)
        fileReader.readLine()
        //Leer el resto del archivo
        var line: String? = fileReader.readLine()
        while (line != null) {
            //recortar la linea leida en partes
            val tokens = line.split(";")
            val cv = ContentValues()
            cv.put(COL_CODE, tokens[code])
            cv.put(COL_NAME, tokens[name])
            cv.put(COL_COMPANY, tokens[company])
            cv.put(COL_DIRECTION, tokens[direction])
            cv.put(COL_NEIGHBORHOOD, tokens[neigh])
            cv.put(COL_PHONE, tokens[phone])
            val result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv)
            if (result == (-1).toLong()) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            line = fileReader.readLine()
        }

        db.close()

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "No se pudo leer este archivo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

-el error en consola es este:
E/File path: /external_files/documents/clientes.csv

-ya tenia funcionando la app con:

```
        val inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.clientes)
        val fileReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream, "ISO-8859-1"))
```

-en lugar de:

```
        val file = FileReader(filepath)
        //Leer el encabezado del archivo CSV
        val fileReader = BufferedReader(file)
```

pero quiero que la actualización de los clientes y los productos sea a traves de la importación de archivos CSV y no de toda la app, agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar, o algun video que no sea en el lenguaje JAVA sino KOTLIN en el que expliquen como importar archivos csv

Comment: Que mensaje de error se muestra en el LogCat? tienes un ejemplo del CSV?

Comment: Bueno el error es E/File path: /external_files/documents/clientes.csv kotlin pero se que el problema esta en que no se como convertir el URI devuelto por el explorador de archivos a inputStream, porque ya lo tenia funcionando bien cuando el archivo estaba dentro de los recursos

Comment: Esto no indica un error "E/File path: /external_files/documents/clientes.csv", a que deseas convertir el URI ?

Comment: quiero convertir ese URI en un inputStream para que BufferedReader haga lo suyo :D